# c# private boolean error inside method

Tags: c#

Sorry for the noobish question and there is probably a very easy fix to this, but I am making an application and I am trying to return a boolean to be used in another method when a checkbox is ticked. Though here I receive an error after the first `{` saying `} expected`. Thanks in advance, P

```
    private void CheckImgur_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        private bool imgurChecked = true;
    }
```

Comment: remove 'private'. You cant have an access modifier within a method, so it should be *bool imgurChecked = true;* or *var imgurChecked = true;*

Comment: Private is for class variables, not for method variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to return a boolean to be used in another method

You can't return a value from an event handler. it's return type is void.

It seems like you meant to assign the value into some field of the class itself.

```
class MyTerrificClass
{
    private bool imgurChecked;


    private void CheckImgur_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.imgurChecked = true;
    }

    private void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // Use this.imgurChecked somewhere
    }
}
```

And in any case local variable doesn't have an access (private/public) modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare variables with access modifiers (-> private) inside of a method. Further if you'd want to return the bool, this is done with the return keyword.

Keep in mind that a method that returns a value of a specific class needs to have this and not void as a return type.

Comment: Is there a way I could utilise the variable elsewhere? Say like an if statement in another method? Like if a button is clicked then check if the variable is true and do something if it is.

Comment: Yes, but be aware that a CheckBox already keeps track of its "checked" state for you in: [CheckBox.Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx)